# How to keep downlaoded package files?

Tags: apt, localrepository

I used to copy deb packages from `/var/cahe/apt/archives` to make my own local repository. Now I realized that apt cleans up `/var/cahe/apt/archives` after each package installation. How can I force apt to keep downloaded files?

Distro: Kubuntu 17.10

**PS**

Pleas note that [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51567/why-does-var-cache-apt-archives-keep-deleting-files) is different. Removing packages immediately after download (rather than using an age, size restriction) is quite different policy controlled by different configuration parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just found a workaround that fixes the issue for me:

```
echo 'Binary::apt::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "1";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01keep-debs
```

I'm not sure why they've changed default behavior. I just lost several gigabytes of bandwidth + a couple of hours.

Hope this helps someone

Comment: this does not work

Comment: Found this on StackExchange. It works: 

Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "true";